# Hardware failure symptoms

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, ext4, sd-card

I believe I have encountered an hardware failure, but would like to be sure of what component/s is causing the problem.

I'm running a raspberry pi zero.

When I have experienced this error, I was running a simple hello_world script and will post an image of the terminal output at the moment of failure.

Are my suspicions correct? Is the SD card to blame for this issue? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Yes, the SD card or the reader or both.

Comment: Check if formatting the SD card helps.

Comment: Thanks for validating my suspicions! My system won't boot up anymore, the SD is probably definitively dead.